# MSSQL Calculate Date Difference in same column

Tags: sql-server

My data is as follows:

```
ID  DATE
1   2014-02-01 09:00:00.00
1   2014-03-01 11:00:00.00
1   2014-01-01 11:00:00.00
2   2010-12-01 05:00:00.00
2   2011-10-01 03:30:00.00
2   2012-09-01 02:40:00.00
```

I need to calculate the date difference(day or hours difference is fine) between each row. The first row can be 0. I have tried:

```
date - coalesce(lag(date) over(order by id, date) as day_difference

daydiff(date - coalesce(lag(date) over(order by id, date)) as day_difference
```

both variants are not working(gives incorrect syntax error).

Please help.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What output are you getting? What output are you expecting? Is the ID important? Is `order by id date` a typo (missing comma)?

Comment: please show data as text

Comment: Posting images for technical information like sample data, instead of text, is the fasted way I know to get your question downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close:

```
datediff(day, date, coalesce(lag(date) over(order by id, date)))  as day_difference
```

But also, you might want to partition by the ID:

```
datediff(day, date, coalesce(lag(date) over(partition by ID order by id, date)))  as day_difference
```

Comment: Thank you so much Joel for updating the table into text form and also the answer. I received the following error(incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order') while implementing your solution.

Comment: I had an extra comma. Fixed now.